# A class for remember me

Tags: javascript

Looking for feedback on correctness and code structure.

Follow up to:

[SStorage (remember) - v0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19825/sstorage-remember-v0)

Note that b.c. the user can only change the storage type when logging in, there is no need to copy back and forth between storage types.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
**SStorage - handles remember option of logging in and namespaces the domain as well
*/
    var SStorage = $A.Class.create({
        Name: 'SStorage',
        A: {

            // storage type
            storage:    null,

            // set the namespace here
            ns:         'arcmarks_',

            // storage key which keeps track of storage type
            indicator:  'arcmarks_h_token'
        },

        // type of storage is set when the user logs in
        // and called below
        setType: function (remember) {
            this.A.storage = remember ? $A.localStorage : $A.sessionStorage;
        },

        // determine type of storage at load MUserAny
        load: function () {
            this.setType($A.localStorage[this.A.indicator]);
        },

        // basic setters and getters with namespacing
        set: function (key, value) {
            this.A.storage[this.A.ns + key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return this.A.storage[this.A.ns + key];
        },
        setObj: function (o) {
            $A.someKey(o, function (val, key) {
                this.A.storage[this.A.ns + key] = val;
            }, this);
        },
        getObj: function () {
            var o = {},
                real_key,
                namespace;
            $A.someKey(this.A.storage, function (val, key) {

                // retrieves after the name-space
                real_key = key.slice(this.A.ns.length);

                // retrieves the name-space
                namespace = key.slice(0, this.A.ns.length);
                if (namespace === this.A.ns) {
                    o[real_key] = val;
                }
            }, this);
            return o;
        },

        // clear only namespaced items
        clear: function () {
            var key;
            for (key in this.A.storage) {
                if (key.slice(0, this.A.len) === this.A.ns) {
                    this.A.storage.removeItem(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: Can I get a comment on why the object (presumably becoming a prototype) has `this.A.foo` instead of `this.foo`?

Comment: just a choice of style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- You are a bit overdoing the blank lines in your definition of `A`
- I like the namespace idea, given how you implement `getObj` and `setObj`, it would be nice if the caller could set the namespace.
- `setType` -> I get that `remember` probably means you want to remember info across sessions, hence you choose `localStorage` and not `sessionStorage`, still something like `persist` or `persistAcrossSessions` could be more informative.
- `setObj` -> does totally not what I would expect it to do, I would expect your code to `JSON.stringify()` and assign that to a key, however you store each property individually which can make for a very messy retrieval
- `getObj` -> does exactly what I thought i would, give all properties in 1 object, this is very limited functionality. You should consider really consider JSON in your class.
- `clear` -> I would make `var key` part of the `for` loop : `for (var key in this.A.storage) {`
- Commenting is uneven, the 2 functions which are most surprising to me have no comments.

Comment: your first comment is a style choice that I picked up from underscorejs.org

Comment: second comment - OK.  Will implement setNameSpace or you may if you like :)

Comment: third comment - style

Comment: 4the comment - we can agree to disagree.  I think that is fine.

Comment: 5th comment - if I wanted to go the JSON route I would use indexedDB instead.

Comment: 6the comment - style again.  I chose jslint style.

Comment: 7th comment - i'll try and add more commenting

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, if you are interested in working on this project let me know.